# How to register .gz format in shutil.register_archive_format to use same format in shutil.unpack_archive

Tags: python-3.x

I have `Example.json.gz` and I want to unpack it or extract it in python using `shutil.unpack_archive()`

However it gives error `shutil.ReadError: Unknown archive format` as `'.gz'` format is not in the list of default format.

So it has to be register first using `shutil.register_archive_format`. Can somebody please help me register and unpack (extract it)

Answer (score 6):

You should define a function that knows how to extract a gz file and then register this function. You could use the gzip library, for instance:

```
import os
import re
import gzip
import shutil
    
    
def gunzip_something(gzipped_file_name, work_dir):
    """gunzip the given gzipped file"""

    # see warning about filename
    filename = os.path.split(gzipped_file_name)[-1]
    filename = re.sub(r"\.gz$", "", filename, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    with gzip.open(gzipped_file_name, 'rb') as f_in:  # <<========== extraction happens here
        with open(os.path.join(work_dir, filename), 'wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
    
    
    try:
      shutil.register_unpack_format('gz', ['.gz', ], gunzip_something)
    except:
      pass
    
    shutil.unpack_archive("Example.json.gz", os.curdir, 'gz')
```

WARNING: if you extract on the same dir where your gzipped file resides and your file does not have a .gz extension I'm not sure what happens (overwrite?).

Comment: This answer worked for me. For people who want to execute it in a loop, take into account that the ``shutl.register_unpack_format(...)`` should be initialized just __once__; otherwise, a ``RegistryError`` will raise.